# How to monitor wordpress plugin usage statistics?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have created a wordpress plugin that I'm about to publish. However I would like to gather statistics of its usage. What would be the best way of doing so? What I have so far is the plugin settings page with opt-in checkbox for user to agree for statistics sharing.

I was thinking of using google statistics but not sure would that be the best option. Most probably the plugin user would already have google analytics on their webpage enabled. Wouldn't that cause a conflict?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How is that 'not programming related'? It's PHP, my friend. Learn to code.

Comment: That's true, but your specific question is not about PHP - as it is, your question is asking for a *recommendation* or *general advice* about the best way to proceed, which is considered off-topic for SO (and really isn't about programming). If you had a question like "this specific PHP code to fire a Google Analyitcs hit is not working", than that would be OK. Please check out the SO page on which topics you can ask about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), or [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you, I will!